ESC POS bitImage command to image
I have a network tap connected to my STAR TSP100III printer enabling me to save the hex commands send to the printer using tcp dump.
The commands are send using the StarPRNT SDK app on my ipad which works great.
I'm trying to recreate the receipt as a bitmap image from the raw hex data. Below is part of the hex data.
**1b**1e4500
**1b**1d03030000
**1b**2a7241
**1b**2a72503000
**1b**2a72453100
**1b**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

The receipt looks like this:
Receipt

Can someone please help me to determine the image size and how to get the receipt as an bitmap image?

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

hex_stream = "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"
binary_string = bin(int(hex_stream, 16))[2:].zfill(len(hex_stream) * 4)

cols = 100
rows = 50
matrix = np.zeros((rows,cols))
for row in range(0,rows):
    for col in range(0,cols): 
        matrix[row,col] = binary_string[row*cols+col]

width = len(matrix[0])
height = len(matrix)
img = Image.new('1', (width, height))

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if matrix[y][x] == 1:
            img.putpixel((x, y), 1)

img.save('test.bmp')
img.show()


The format of the ESC/POS command used in image printing is described on page 49 of this document ESC/POS Mode Command Specifications, so please try parsing it with a program according to its contents.
